# How to calculate average and latest cost of a product over date range in same sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average, subquery

I have table where product is there and it's cost over a time range. I need to calculate the average cost over the period, with the latest cost till date to be considered in average also I need to fetch the current cost. How can I achieve it in same query.

Input Table

[image: 700999]

I am looking for output like

product | average_cost | current_cost

(average cost is (cost*days of that cost)/total days dill today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetic and conditional aggregation:

```
select product,
       ( sum( cost * datediff(day, beg_date, (case when end_date > getdate() then getdate() else end_date end) )) /
         sum(datediff(day, beg_date, (case when end_date > getdate() then getdate() else end_date end))
       ) as avg_price,
       max(case when end_date > getdate() then price end)
from t
group by product;
```